# MeshAnim animation in BDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to create a small swinging animation in my BDX game. But even though i get no errors, nothing appears to be animated and i don't quite understand what im doing wrong. Can anyone tell me what im missing here? `

```
public void init(){
MeshAnimma = new MeshAnim(this);
ma.add("swing", new String[]{"Cylinder.002","Cylinder.003","Cylinder.004","Cylinder.005","Cylinder.006","Cylinder.007","Cylinder.008"},12,true);
components.add(ma);
}

public void main(){
if (Bdx.keyboard.keyHit("space"))
{
    System.out.println("Swing");
    ma.play("swing");
    }
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, Parent was set to invisible.